# Getting Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. when spreading props and composing multiple Mui components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am a bit puzzled by this, i'm composing multiple Material ui components together to mimic the pattern in TextField, for a Select Field.

When i create a story in storybook, this is fine. but when it's a server rendered page, it behaves properly but I am getting the unique key warning

```
export const SelectField: React.FunctionComponent<SelectFieldProps> = ({
  label,
  SelectProps,
  children,
  disabled,
  helperText,
  error,
  className,
  name,
  id,
  value,
  onChange,
  onBlur,
  fullWidth,
}) => {
  const labelClasses = useLabelStyles();
  const helperTextClasses = useHelperStyles();
  const formControlClasses = useFormControlStyles({ fullWidth });
  // TODO investivate className server client mismatch with props in dev mode
  const width = fullWidth ? '100%' : 'auto';

  const inputLabel = React.useRef<HTMLLabelElement>(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel?.current?.offsetWidth ?? 0);
  }, []);

  return (
    <FormControl
      classes={formControlClasses}
      style={{ width }}
      className={className}
      variant="filled"
      error={error}
      disabled={disabled}
    >
      {label && (
        <InputLabel classes={labelClasses} htmlFor={id ? id : SelectProps?.inputProps?.id}>
          {label}
        </InputLabel>
      )}
      <Select
        {...SelectProps}
        labelWidth={labelWidth}
        label={label}
        disabled={disabled ?? SelectProps?.disabled}
        name={name ?? SelectProps?.inputProps?.name}
        id={id ?? SelectProps?.inputProps?.id}
        value={value ?? SelectProps?.value}
        onChange={onChange ?? SelectProps?.onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur ?? SelectProps?.onBlur}
      >
        {children}
      </Select>
      {helperText && <FormHelperText classes={helperTextClasses}>{helperText}</FormHelperText>}
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

and my usage of it roughly:

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={sm}>
                <SelectField
                  fullWidth
                  name="isoCountryCode"
                  id="isoCountryCode"
                  label="Country"
                  SelectProps={{
                    inputProps: {
                      'data-testid': 'country-code',
                      autoComplete: 'country',
                    },
                  }}
                >
                  <option value="" />
                  {IsoCountryCodes.map(({ value, key, label }) => (
                    <option value={value} key={key}>
                      {label}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </SelectField>
              </Grid>
```

and yes the option values are unique. I also got the error when I took that part out :)

any ideas?

here's the issue link that was closed by the support bot:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20104

Comment: Isn't the problem because you've been using Capital first? I think it may think you are trying to use Component

Comment: Is the issue because of spreading props or is it because of the htmlFor in your InputLabel?

Comment: I forgot to mention, my workaround was to remove the spread and put what I needed in instead of SelectProps. Are you saying because it’s capitalized that’s causing some issue jsx wise?

Comment: htmlFor is valid. Taking it out results in same issue

Comment: see https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L150 I am not having any issues with this component.

Comment: tried putting `SelectProps` into a new object with lowercase, `otherSelectProps` and still has same issue.
```
const other = { ...SelectProps }
```